# Angular and Breeze multiple EntityManagers

Tags: angularjs, breeze

My angular application uses Breeze and encapsulates the breeze calls within a datacontext service. How can I use this service with different EntityManagers? I am thinking that I need to abandon using the datacontext as an angular service in this situation, since it seems like it is going to require maintaining state.

How do others deal with this? I really hate not being able to use the angular service, but I also want to have re-use of the datacontext with a different EntityManager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know enough about your requirements to give a specific answer. But I wouldn't be so quick to abandon the "datacontext" abstraction.

> This question appears to be related to your [*other question here*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30242279/breezejs-handling-lookup-tables-across-modules) which seems to be the "sandbox" case. I'll pick up the thread there.

Sometimes I need multiple `EntityManagers` when I need to talk to multiple services, each with its own entity model. And when that happens I typically have a different workflow for each service in which case I should have separate "datacontexts" for each workflow. Problem "solved" :-)

Sometimes I'll want two `EntityManagers` for the same service because I'm "sandboxing". I "sandbox" when I need two copies of the same nominal entity:

1. A read-only version representing the state of the entity on the database
2. A mutable version holding the user's unsaved changes.

I might implement this scenario with separate "datacontexts" too

1. The main, read-only datacontext handling most of the app's data access needs.
2. An "editing" datacontext, smaller than the first, focused on the edit/save workflow.

Each datacontext has its own instance of an `EntityManager`. Each instance is mostly configured the same way and typically has the same metadata.

I might create a `SandboxContextFactory` service to create new instances of the specialized datacontext. Each such `SandboxContext` has its own `EntityManager`.

I tend to write an `EntityManagerProvider` (EMP) service to create `EntityManager`s and inject this into the datacontext services. This EMP can create and coordinate multiple instances of a commonly configured "master" `EntityManager`.

The EMP might:

- Create a "master" `EntityManager` at the start.
- Populate that "master" with metadata (via `fetchMetadata` call)
- Populate the "master" with app-wide reference entities (e.g., "lookup" entities).
- Create new "sandbox" managers when asked, perhaps by.

  - cloning the master: `var childEm = masterEm.createEmptyCopy();`
  - populating the child with common data from the master (e.g., reference entities). You can do that easily by [exporting](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html#method_exportEntities) the pertinent entities from master and [importing](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html#method_importEntities) them into the child.

Hope these architectural speculations inspire a solution appropriate for you.  If you need help developing your application along these lines, you might consider engaging [IdeaBlade's professional services](https://www.ideablade.com/services).

Comment: Thanks Ward.That is helpful.
I had actually been looking at your TempHire sample and the way you are using repositories. I am taking a similar approach and that seems to be working well so far.
 
The disconnect I was having was that in the Breeze/Angular examples that I've seen the datacontext is being built as Angular service. This works great for a single EntityManger scenario or a shared scenario where the EntityManager is always going to be the same. But in the sandbox scenario, you don't actually know what EntityManager will be used with the datacontext.

Comment: I don't supposed any of you have had to have multiple entity managers where one is odata and one is webapi?